# Is there anyway to use MySQL's LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, xml, load, local, file-io

with this type of XML format?

```
<details>
  <detail>
    <name>Woofer Size</name>
    <value>12"</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Woofer Material</name>
    <value>KEVLAR-reinforced pulp</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Magnet Size</name>
    <value>74 oz.</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Continuous Power Handling</name>
    <value>250W</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Peak Power handling</name>
    <value>750W</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Impedance</name>
    <value>4 ohms</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Number of Voice Coils</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Frame Material</name>
    <value>Steel</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
    <name>Surround Material</name>
    <value>Santoprene rubber</value>
  </detail>
  <detail>
```

I do not know how to approach this problem of getting the data into a MySQL database. My Question is: Is it possible to load this directly into MySQL?

**UPDATE**

The solution was to create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE data(
   name VARCHAR(250),
   value VARCHAR(250));
```

Then use this statement:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE
'path/to/the/file.xml'
INTO TABLE data ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<detail>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, assuming you have a well-formed XML doc, which your example isn't.
See [LOAD XML Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)

> This statement supports three different XML formats:
>
> - Column names as attributes and column values as attribute values:
>
> `<row column1="value1" column2="value2" .../>`
>
> - Column names as tags and
>     column values as the content of these tags:

```
<row>
    <column1>value1</column1>
    <column2>value2</column2> 
</row>
```

> - Column names are the name attributes of  tags, and values are
>     the contents of these tags:

```
<row>   
    <field name='column1'>value1</field>   
    <field name='column2'>value2</field> 
</row>
```

It is the second format that should work in your case.

Comment: If I'm not reading it wrong, I still face a problem because the tag names of my XML doc are not unique and are redundant.

Comment: They are unique: `name` is different than `value`. Those are your column names.